# SSL сертификат внутри локальной сети

Tags: сеть, администрирование, ssl, https, dns

Здраствуйте. Есть веб приложение использующее **getUserMedia()** на телефонах и этот метод работает только в том случае если страница была загружена с помощью протокола **https**. Но здесь есть проблема, приложение работает во **внутренней локальной сети** и я не могу заказать сертификаты так как домен приложения находится в локальной сети(не будет доступа из вне и соотвественно не смогу подтвердить владение доменом).
Приложение находится на windows server 2008 r2 IIS 7
Можно использовать самоподписанные сертификаты, но тогда будут выходить предупреждения что подключение не защищено.

Пока вижу решение только купить какой-нибудь домен, сделать сертификат и в рабочем ДНС сделать перенаправление с этого домена на нужный адрес, но это как-то сложновато. Может быть уже сталкивался кто-то с этим?

Comment: А просто добавить самоподписанный сертификат в доверенные на всех нужных устройствах?

Comment: https://blog.heckel.io/2018/08/05/issuing-lets-encrypt-certificates-for-65000-internal-servers/

Comment: Если это нормальный публичный домен, то его всегда можно подтвердить через DNS. Если это какой-то внутренний непубличный, то самоподписанный сертификат

Comment: А в сети используется Active Directory ?

Comment: нет,  Active Directory нет к сожалению(или к счастью)